# Why Rust outperforms C so much

Tags: c, rust

For many years I use this very simple program to get a rough estimate of the programming language performance. I have a dozen of versions in Ruby (600 ms), Python (1500 ms), JavaScript (45 ms), C (25 ms both GCC/Clang on my notebook) and other languages. Do not make serious conclusions based on such a simple benchmark, because it is far from any real life case. I call it "classic" simply because I use it for decades already. Maybe even saying "a rough estimate" is too much. This test is extremely simple, mostly because writing better test for a language you do not know is time consuming and I usually write it when I get my hands on the new language for the first time. Sometimes, though, I will run the test few years later when the compiler/interpreter gets an update. Anyway recently I ported this test to(for?) Rust and was really surprised because it outperformed previous record holder C about three times (7 ms!~@!). My question is for those who know something about Rust compilation, why is it so fast? I know it uses LLVM just as Clang so I expected about the same speed (Just as Nim performs about as C because it compiles to C, though not very efficiently and is still about two time slower than C when this simple benchmark is run).

**Rust**

```rust
// rustc --color always -C opt-level=3 -C prefer-dynamic classic.rs  -C link-args=-s -o classic.rust

use std::ptr;

#[repr(C)]
struct timeval {
    tv_sec: i64,
    tv_usec: i64
}

extern {
    fn gettimeofday(tv: &mut timeval, tzp: *const ()) -> i32;
}

fn time1000() -> i64 {
    let mut tv = timeval { tv_sec: 0, tv_usec: 0 };
    unsafe {
        gettimeofday(&mut tv, ptr::null());
    }
    tv.tv_sec * 1000 + tv.tv_usec / 1000
}

fn classic() {
    let mut a:i64 = 3000000;
    loop {
        a = a - 1;
        if a == 0 { break; }
        let mut b = (a / 100000) as i64;
        b = b * 100000;
        if a == b { print!("{} ", a); }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut t = time1000();
    classic();
    t = time1000() - t;
    println!("{}", t);
}
```

**C**

```c
#include "stdio.h"
#include <sys/time.h>

long time1000() {
    struct timeval val;
    gettimeofday(&val, 0);
    return val.tv_sec * 1000 + val.tv_usec / 1000;
}

void classic() {
    double a = 3000000, b;
    while (1) {
        a--;
        if (a == 0) break;
        b = a / 100000;
        b = (int) b;
        b *= 100000;
        if (a == b) { printf("%i ", (int)a); }
    }
}

int main() {
    int T = time1000();
    classic();
    T = time1000() - T;
    printf("%i", (int)T);
}
```

Comment: Also, you're benchmarking code that includes I/O, so it's basically meaningless.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: That could be part of the answer. My first suspicion would be that Rust has some optimised (or with less features) console output compared with C.

Comment: Last time I checked, the POSIX mandated locking glibc stdio  was slower compared to classic stdio about 4 times. It might be the culprit.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I can live with the downvotes, but if the question is closed I will not get an answer and I am curious and need an answer because Rust is a promise.

Comment: IO has nothing to do with this performance gain. Increase the constants 10 times or 1000 times, you get as much IO (about 200 characters) and the program runs for seconds or minutes. The difference in performance between C and Rust remains the same -- 3 times.

Comment: Also worth noting that `i64` != `double`...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth that's just another way to compare `a modulo 1e5`.

Comment: @exebook - But you're using fundamentally different types.  Why would you expect the performance to be the same?

Comment: Benchmarks that measure useless code are useless. To get meaningful benchmark results, benchmark meaningful programs.

Comment: If you guys are so knowledgable why nobody answers the question.

Comment: Because you don't have a valid question. You are asking "Why Rust outperforms C" without having shown that Rust does in fact outperform C, or anything close to that.

Comment: The question does not deserve the downvotes: it does show research effort, it is a clear question, and it is useful. But it does deserve a close, because it's centered on what's basically a typo.

Answer (score 4):

Substitute

```
int64_t a = 3000000, b;
```

for

```
double a = 3000000, b;
```

to make it equivalent (on a 64 bit arch.) with

```
   let mut a:i64 = 3000000;
   //...
   let mut b = (a / 100000) as i64;
```

and C wins (even with stdio).
On my PC, C is about 1.4–1.5 times faster (-O3, measured on a 100-iteration shell for-loop to discount startup overhead).

Comment: How to do it the other way around (use float in Rust)?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Good point (though portability is probably not much of a concern in quick and dirty benchmarks).

Comment: @exebook: Change the types. E.g. replace `i64` with `f64`, and change all the literals.